# How to check if proxy settings in WebClient work?

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a `WebClient` object with the `Proxy` property set.

But when using the `WebClient` object the communication is transparent so there is no proxy in effect.

How do I check programmatically during runtime if (for example before downloading a file with that `WebClient` object) the proxy connection works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question:

You could set up a Proxy Server on your computer, such as [CCProxy](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/wiki.htm) (Or something similar).  Point your WebClient application to that proxy server.  Then [enable logging](http://www.youngzsoft.net/ccproxy/advanced-options.htm) on CCProxy to see if the traffic you expected is passing through.

**EDIT**

Are you in a network that restricts internet access unless you are using a proxy server?

If your network supports it, you could look into Automatic Proxy Detection https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fze2ytx2(v=vs.110).aspx

> When automatic proxy detection is enabled, the system attempts to locate a proxy configuration script that is responsible for returning the set of proxies that can be used for the request. If the proxy configuration script is found, the script is downloaded, compiled, and run on the local computer when proxy information, the request stream, or the response is obtained for a request that uses a WebProxy instance.

The reason it is hard to know if the problem is proxy settings is; when your app tries to connect to the internet, it cannot possibly know or guess that the reason the URL is not accessible is because you need to use a proxy.  So it throws a general exception.   Because there are many reasons why a URL might not be accessible, such as, Internet service is down, network misconfiguration, or like in your case, a proxy setting is required.  Your app would be guessing as to which one of those reasons the URL is inaccessible.

Comment: I meant how to check it programmatically during runtime

Comment: Oh! sorry I misinterpreted your question.    Wouldn't WebClient throw an exception if it can't connect to the Proxy?

Comment: It throws an exception because it cannot access the URL without the proxy but it doesn't say why it couldn't access the URL. So I want to log if the cause is the proxy server.

Comment: @Palmi could you edit your question to better reflect what you are asking?  After reading your last comment, It sounds like you want to know how to detect if a proxy is required to reach the outside of your network.  I have edited my answer to hopefully better align with what you are asking.